# TFS 2010/VS 2010: Deployment of database project changes to test environment

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, deployment, project

We have a system consisting of a winforms client, a bunch of web services, a bunch of reporting services reports and a database with a corresponding database project in VS 2010.

We use TFS as source control system and for automatic builds etc.

When our tester queues a new build from within the Build Explorer, our client and server is build and the server is deployed to the web server. Reports and database changes are not deployed automatically.

Is it possible to have the changes from the database project deployed automatically to the test database whenever a new test build is queued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Your build template can invoke VSDBCMD.exe to do a comparison between your database project (.dbschema) and your test database in order to generate and execute a script that will update your test database.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx) is info about VSDBCMD.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805001.aspx) is the procedure to setup your build template to use VSDBCMD.